# How to shut of my iphone 4s

Tags: iphone

I'm unable to turn off my iphone 4s.  I've attempted several times by holding the top right button down then slide the shut off prompt off but moments later it pops back on.   Currently the phone doesn't hold a charged and gets hot. This activity has been happening for a few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it actually rebooting, or failing to shutdown?

You can try a hard reset. Hold both the power button (that you've been using) and the home button in until the device reboots.